# Encoded categorical features in h2o in python

Tags: python, h2o, categorical-data

Is there a way to see how the categorical features are encoded when we allow h2o to automatically create categorical data by casting a column to `enum` type?

I am implementing holdout stacking where my underlying training data differs for each model. I have a common feature that I want to make sure is encoded the same way across both sets. The feature contains names (str). It is guaranteed that all names that appear in one data set will be appear in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to see inside a model is to export the pojo, and look at the java source code. You should see how it is processing enums.

But, if I understand the rest of your question correctly, it should be fine. As long as the training data contains all possible values of a category it will work as you expect. If a categorical value not see in training is presented in production it will be treated as an NA.